# Use API to populate SQL Server DB

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, .net, sql-server

I am relatively new to this so if this is a dumb question please just link me to some relevant information.

We work with a third party vendor that recently opened up their databases using an API. Information on it can be found here: https://www.entrata.com/api-documentation. It returns the data in either an XML or JSON format as per usual.

We would like to use this API to copy relevant data onto our own SQL server so we can preform our own reporting (their provided reports aren't quite up to snuff with what we are looking for). We want this to be done regularly so I am really looking for a repeatable process. I have been searching around and I believe I am going to have to build a .NET application that GETs the data then parses it into a SQL friendly format for BULK INSERT, but I'm not sure if this is indeed the case or where to really start if it is.

Any information you can provide or even a point in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time and effort.

P.S. At the moment I do not have access to our SQL server. I have been trying to get a logon from our IT department for the last week but they seem to be dragging their feet.

Comment: General bids for assistance are considered off-topic.

Comment: Are you sure the vendor isn't willing to just send you a nightly/weekly/whatever copy of the database?

Comment: Sounds perfectly doable - practice to sql developer on your pc

Comment: You could save the XML files to a folder and do an ``INSERT OR UPDATE`` query on your tables.  You can read from them using ``OPENROWSET`` in a SQL query.  Really the only programming you would have to do is getting the XML files, I believe.  Get them, run the SQL job reading from the XML using ``OPENROWSET`` and then ``INSERT OR UPDATE``.  There also could be a way to get the XML directly from a http://....xml file from their API. I don't know enough about that to comment.

Comment: Amy - Sorry, is there somewhere better I can post this?

Comment: I think you would be just fine if you refine your question to something more specific.

Comment: Itsme - They are willing to do so but my company has apparently run into a few failed projects in the past going that route.

Comment: Justice - Thank you for your input. I will look into that. I have had some experience with that so it may be the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) to develop a package that imports the data.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169917.aspx